# how to automate excel with python

Tags: python, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKryf.png)

how to replace each SEGMENT with number of rows below SEGMENT automatically using python?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do review the guidelines for posting questions. In general you should not post images of your data as it makes it hard for anyone to either try to reproduce errors or guide you towards a solution. Also, it is required to post your own attempts to a solution, even if it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will replace all occurrences of the word "SEGMENT" with the length of the rows under it until a new "SEGMENT" occurs.

You need to install the `openpyxl` pip package with `pip install openpyxl`

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="yourFile.xlsx")

sheet = workbook.active

text = ""

# Iterator for row in sheet
i = 0
for x in sheet:
    i += 1
    # Append to text
    text += str(sheet[f"A{i}"].value) + "\n"


# Iterator
i = -1
# Index of SEGMENT
j = 1
# last index of SEGMENT
k = 0

# All the values which all the SEGMENTS will be replaced through
newVars = []
for x in text.split("SEGMENT"):
    # Increase the iterator
    i += 1
    # Append the length of vars minus 2 (The Segment before and after)
    newVars.append(len(text.split("SEGMENT")[i].split("\n"))-2)

# Remove the first item (-1)
del newVars[0]

# Iterator of rows
i = 0
# Iterator of SEGMENTS
j = 0
for x in sheet:
    i += 1
    if sheet[f"A{i}"].value == "SEGMENT":
        # Replacing the value with !{lenOfRows}
        sheet[f"A{i}"].value = "!" + str(newVars[j])
        # Increasing the iterator for the SEGMENTS
        j += 1

        
# Save the file
workbook.save(filename="yourFile.xlsx")

# Just a print
print("Everything got replaced")
```

This code can be improved but it should work

**Note**: everything has to be in the `A` column in that Excel file.

Of course you need to replace the filenames with yours

Answer (score 0):

If you can save your Excel document in *.csv* format, you could do something like this, using just python's file i/o.

This answer is accounting for your specific question that has only one column. Using python csv library or openpyxl is probably easier for multiple columns.

### Note

The code assumes the input file is named *segments.csv* and it's saving to a new file named *output.csv*.

```py
output = []
SEGMENT = "SEGMENT"

with open("segments.csv", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().split()
    count = 0
    segment_index = -1

    # fills the output with segment counts
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line == SEGMENT:
            if segment_index != -1:
                output[segment_index] = str(count)
            count = 0
            segment_index = i
        else:
            count += 1
        output.append(line)
        
    # accounts for the last segment
    if segment_index != - 1:
        output[segment_index] = str(count)

# writes output content to a new file 
with open("output.csv", 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(output))
```